# Excel: Unique symbols based on input

Tags: excel, charts, unique, series, symbols

Every quarter I receive a dataset that I am then have to chart and report in a very quick turnaround. The datasets include many many groups of data like the attached figure. For each data grouping, I need the data to plot a scatterplot with lines and markers, where the x-axis is the COLLECTION_DT and the y-axis is the PLOTVALUE. There will be separate series for the different STATION_ID values. The markers for each series should be a different shape based on the QUALIFIER_CD, as shown in the figure. Is there a more efficient way to make the datasets do this? For my actual datasets I have much more data and many of these groupings to do consistently and the time spent on this is significant.

[Data Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gm1lV.png)

The only way I have successfully done this so far is by creating a separate data series for the data (e.g., orange line), separate series for the "U" values (orange, empty square), separate series for the "J" values (orange, empty circles), and separate series for " " values (orange, filled circle). This is time consuming.

I was hoping there was a way to select the entire dataset and then choose symbology that reflects the unique field QUALIFIER_CD.

Comment: What about a template with all the charts and calculations set up referring to a sheet where you just refresh the data? So open the template, paste the new data and save_as the new filename...